# Serve custom javascript to browser via Node.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, rest

I developed a small node.js app in which I can configure conditions for a custom javascript file, which can be embedded in a webpage, and which modifies the DOM of that page in the browser on load. The configuration values are stored in MongoDB. (For sake of argument: add class "A" to DOM element with ID "B" )

I have difficulties to figure out the best way to serve requests / the JavaScript file.

**Option 1 and my current implementation is:**

- I save a configuration in the node app and a distinct JavaScript
  file is created for that configuration.
- The page references that file which is hosted and served by the server.

**Option 2 and where I think I want and should go is:**

- I saves a configuration (mongodb) NO JavaScript file is created Pages
  a generic JavaScript link (for instance: api.service.com/javascript.js)
- Node.js / Express app processes the request, and
- returns a custom JavaScript (file?) with the correct values as saved in mongodb for that configuration

Now, while I believe this is the right way to go about it, I am unsure HOW to go about it. Any ideas and advise are very welcome!

Ps: For instance I wonder how best to authenticate or identify the origin, user and requested configuration. Shall I do this like: api.service.com/javascript.js&id="userID" - is that good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Why not serve up a generic Javascript file which can take a customized json object (directly from mongodb) and apply the necessary actions? You can include the json data on the page if you really need to have everything embedded, but breaking up configuration and code is the most maintainable approach.